# How I am scan MEM_PRIVATE and MEM_RESERVE memory block?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, memory-leaks, readprocessmemory

I am try to get address of any string (I know there is so much example for that but Its not for me). I can get all address(or pointer) MEM_MAPPED and MEM_IMAGE type of pages in the region but I cant get MEM_PRIVATE page region, my char or string in MEM_RESERVE and MEM_PRIVATE

[image: processhacker screenshot]

(I am trying to get 0x2b6f000)

```
std::string const& pattern = "d3dtext_chat";
DWORD procid = 8292;
unsigned char* addr = 0;

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procid);

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
{
    if (mbi.State == MEM_RESERVE && mbi.Type == MEM_PRIVATE)
    {
        std::cout << "base : 0x" << std::hex << mbi.BaseAddress << "\n";    
    }
    addr += mbi.RegionSize;
}
```

I can get the memory region (private and reserve) with this code and then I use RPM(readprocessmemory) and I use memcmp to find my char or string. It is for to get mapped and image region but I cant get private region, what should be I do?

Comment: Unless memory has been committed, there's nothing in a reserved region of address space.

Comment: okey... how i am get my specific string address from process memory ?

Comment: A reserved range of address space doesn't contain any memory. If you want to find a pattern in memory, it's not there. There is nothing in this range.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Well then, if its not in a certain range, why doesnt the address change constantly ?

Comment: Not a question I can answer, given the information I have. I don't know, what you are ultimately trying to accomplish, nor which program's memory you are trying to read, or why. It's wildly unclear why the address of some undisclosed piece of data doesn't change, nor why that is relevant.

Comment: The question is so basic, I want to get address of specific string from another process. If you want to see quick example go processhacker and double click any process and select memory and then click strings... JUST SELECT PRIVATE and do minimum lenght 4, I want to get there are address any string

Comment: If you want to find a pattern in memory you have to search through memory. Ranges of memory whose `State` is reported as `MEM_RESERVE` *"indicates reserved pages where a range of the process's virtual address space is reserved without any physical storage being allocated."* Trying to read from memory that doesn't exist doesn't appear to be a meaningful operation. You might want to read about [memory management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/memory-management) in Windows.